# How to use --from-file option in systrace: Always Gives error No data was captured. Output file was not written

Tags: android, systrace

systrace is tool which helps analyze the performance of your application by capturing and displaying execution times of your applications processes and other Android system processes.

There are multiple command line options are given to capture and visualize the traces by using systrace

I am specifically looking for usage of option --from-file.
From Android Studio page: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/systrace-commandline.html

It is mentioned that :
**--from-file=** Create the interactive Systrace report from a file, instead of running a live trace.

And within systrace.py this is the code snippet which explain the usage.

```
parser.add_option('--from-file', dest='from_file', action='store',
                help='read the trace from a file (compressed) rather than '
                'running a live trace')
```

So we can visualize the data which we captured offline, with command

```
python systrace.py --from-file systrace_check_zip
```

But I see that it always returns  **error**:

**No data was captured.  Output file was not written.**

Is someone familiar with `--from-file` ? how to use it ?

Am I doing this wrong way ?

**NOTE** I am passing the compressed (zip) data taken from atrace.